# Django Rest Docs Show Wrong Urls

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, api-design

I'm using the [Django Rest Docs](https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-docs) to describe my API built in the Django Rest Framework, but the urls it's displaying are incorrect. Specifically, they prepend /admin/ to everything:

[image]

These paths should be /session-auth/, /session/, etc. I don't know why the /admin/ is being preprended. Here's my urls.py file:

```
# URLs for serving static media and user uploaded media
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_URL, 'show_indexes': True}),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


urlpatterns += patterns('myapp.views',
    #Home page
    (r'^$', 'home'),

    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_docs.urls')),

    # Refresh all locations
    (r'^admin/refresh-all-locations/$', 'refresh_all_locations'),
    # Admin all locations page
    (r'^admin/all-locations/$', admin.site.admin_view(all_locations)),
    # Admin
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    ####API urls####
    # Authenticate a user
    url(r'^session-auth/$', API.Session.SessionAuth.as_view(), name='authenticate'),
    # Update user password or email
    url(r'^session/$', API.Session.SessionDetail.as_view()),

    # Get the detail on one entity
    url(r'^entities/(?P<entity_id>[0-9]+)/$', API.Entity.EntityDetail.as_view()),
```

Comment: can you access your `session-auth` API without preprended `admin` in your browser?

Comment: Yeah, the URLs still work fine for the API.

Comment: Just notice that your url patterns is not consistent. some urls are wrapping with `url(..)`, some some urls you just use `(r'....')`? why not use `urlpatterns += [url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_docs.urls')), url(r'^session-auth/$', API.Session.SessionAuth.as_view(), name='authenticate'),...]`

Comment: all urls warp with `url()` function

Comment: Tried that, no change.